# Showing records with same last name but different first names with one of first names meeting a criteria

Tags: select

My SQL query is more complex than this but this part I am stuck. For example if I had a table:

```
lname        fname
--------     -----
Mitchell     Jason
Miles        Ryan
Miles        Mary
Mitchell     Craig
Payne        Jason
```

I want to show only rows where the first name is Jason and there exist another record with the same last name.

So it should only show

```
lname       fname
--------    -----
Mitchell    Jason 
Mitchell    Craig
```

Comment: What query(s) have you tried so far? What database are you running your query against (eg, SQLServer, Postgres, Oracle, ???)?

Comment: Well my data set was a little more complicated that what I described but I try to give an example to related to what I was doing. Pretty much had something to the fact of:  select a.lname, a.fname from table1 a where a.fname = 'Jason' Union  select b.lname, b.fname from table1 b where b.fname <>  'Jason' having count(*) >1

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH cte AS ( SELECT t1.lname, 
                     t1.fname, 
                     COUNT(t1.fname) OVER (PARTITION BY t2.lname) cnt
              FROM tbl t1, 
                   tbl t2 
              WHERE t1.lname = t2.lname 
                AND t2.fname = 'Jason'
             )
SELECT lname, fname
FROM cte
WHERE cnt > 1
```

Test it on the fiddle in the [chittybang](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/164945/chittybang)'s [answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/222736/150107).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using SQL Server you could do something like this:

```
SELECT c.lname, c.fname
FROM tbl as c
WHERE c.lname IN (SELECT a.lname
                    FROM 
        tbl as a inner join
        (SELECT lname
                          FROM tbl
                          GROUP BY lname
                          HAVING COUNT (lname)> 1)
                    AS b on a.lname = b.lname 
    WHERE a.fname = 'Jason');
```

You can test it out in this [fidlle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c72755fc31ac989b028286082222c296)

Hope this helps you.